# C++ Abstract / Concrete Class Declaration

Tags: c++, abstract-class, concreteclass

I have a MotorDefinition class and an abstract class called Motor:

```
class MotorDefinition {
public:
    MotorDefinition(int p1, int p2, int p3) : pin1(p1), pin2(p2), pin3(p3) {}
    int pin1 = -1;
    int pin2 = -1;
    int pin3 = -1;
};
class Motor {
public:
     Motor(MotorDefinition d) : definition(d) {}
     virtual void forward(int speed) const = 0;
     virtual void backward(int speed) const = 0;
     virtual void stop() const = 0;
protected:
    MotorDefinition definition;
};
```

My Zumo vehicle has two motors:

```
class MotorTypeZumoLeft : public Motor {
    MotorTypeZumoLeft(MotorDefinition def) : Motor(def) {}
    void Motor::forward(int speed) const {}
    void Motor::backward(int speed) const {}
    void Motor::stop() const {}
};

class MotorTypeZumoRight : public Motor {
    MotorTypeZumoRight(MotorDefinition def) : Motor(def) {}
    void Motor::forward(int speed) const {}
    void Motor::backward(int speed) const {}
    void Motor::stop() const {};
};

class MotorTypeZumo {
public:
     MotorTypeZumo(MotorTypeZumoLeft *l, MotorTypeZumoRight *r) : left(l), right(r) {}

protected:
    MotorTypeZumoLeft *left;
    MotorTypeZumoRight *right;

};
```

Unfortunately (for me), this doesn't compile:

```
MotorDefinition lmd(1, 2, 3);
MotorTypeZumoLeft *leftMotor(lmd);
MotorDefinition rmd(4, 5, 6);
MotorTypeZumoRight *rightMotor(rmd);
MotorTypeZumo motors(*leftMotor, *rightMotor);
```

I think I am missing some fundamental concepts and I am certainly messing up some syntax. Can you help me define this correctly, please.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't work, because you cannot initialize a pointer variable with a `MotorDefinition` instance.

```
MotorTypeZumoLeft *leftMotor(lmd);
```

---

You probably did not intend `leftMotor` to be a pointer.

```
MotorTypeZumoLeft leftMotor(lmd);
```

Similarly for `rightMotor`.

```
MotorTypeZumoRight rightMotor(rmd);
```

You need to pass addresses to initialize `motors`:

```
MotorTypeZumo motors(&leftMotor, &rightMotor);
```

---

However, if you did intend for `leftMotor` and `rightMotor` to be pointers, it would be better to use a smart pointer rather than a raw pointer.

```
auto leftMotor = std::make_unique<MotoTypeZumoLeft>(lmd);
auto rightMotor = std::make_unique<MotoTypeZumoRight>(lmd);
```

And, you should modify `MotorTypeZumo` to also use smart pointers.

```
class MotorTypeZumo {
public:
     MotorTypeZumo(
          std::unique_ptr<MotorTypeZumoLeft> &l,
          std::unique_ptr<MotorTypeZumoRight> &r)
    : left(std::move(l)), right(std::move(r)) {}
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<MotorTypeZumoLeft> left;
    std::unique_ptr<MotorTypeZumoRight> right;
};
```

Then, you can just pass `leftMotor` and `rightMotor` to `motors`.

```
MotorTypeZumo motors(leftMotor, rightMotor);
```